# Reload the GridView BoundField columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm removing some BoundField columns from my Gridview at runtime. I want to reload the GridView without refreshing the page (like on a button click).

My Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < NoOfDays; i++)
{
    gridview_Calendar.Columns.RemoveAt(gridview_Calendar.Columns.Count - 2);
}
```

How to restore those removed columns?

Comment: Are you trying to reload the columns in the same request or in separate requests?  If you want to do it in separate requests, then you need to look into using Ajax so that you won't have to refresh the entire page.

Comment: It is in a seperate request and in an update panel, however the columns removed are not getting restored.

Comment: Please show the code where you're trying to restore the columns and it's not working.  I think that would help a lot in diagnosing the problem here.  Also, show (or mention) the context of your code (when / where it's being called).  For instance, the code you have in your question - where is that called (Page_Load, on a button click, etc)?

Comment: Also, what action is supposed to restore the columns?  Does that action also cause the UpdatePanel to perform asynchronous update of itself?

Comment: @AaronHawkins yes the click event is set in the trigger

Comment: @user2133810 - Are you refreshing the grid in this click event?

Comment: Please show the click event.  That would mitigate all of this discussion in the comments.  You can use the "edit" button to update your question.